# Keys for components in React

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 buttons and information about div. When I click on one of the buttons, I want the component to appear in the information block. But my keys are transferred by index. How can I make it so that the key is not an index for a component?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Donald from '/.Donald';
import John from '/.John';

class Names extends Component {
    state = {
      key: 1
    };

    components =  {
        1: <Donald/>,
        2:<John/>
    };


   showComponent = key => {
     this.setState({ key });
   };

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <div className="info">{this.components[this.state.key]}</div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={ () => this.showComponent(1) }>My name Donald</button>
          <button onClick={ () => this.showComponent(2)}>My name John</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Names;
```

Comment: Do you want to show just one component at the same time or multiple by clicking buttons?

Comment: And what do you mean that keys are transferred by index ?

Comment: one, but when you press the button, it changed

Comment: Don't you want to it won't change when button clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Just edit a little your code like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Donald from '/.Donald';
import John from '/.John';

class Names extends Component {
    state = {
      component: null
    };

    components =  {
        'donald': <Donald/>,
        'john' :<John/>
    };

   showComponent = component => {
     this.setState({ component });
   };

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <div className="info">{this.components[this.state.component]}</div>
        <div>
          {this.state.component !== 'donald' && <button onClick={ () => this.showComponent('donald') }>My name Donald</button>}
          {this.state.component !== 'john' && <button onClick={ () => this.showComponent('john')}>My name John</button>}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Names;
```

You could make a better one with a `switch` for instance, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use keys, by using `different ids and switch-case for components` you can achieve this scenario.This is a working solution of your problem.

```js
const Donald = () => <div>Rendering Component Donald</div>;
const John = () => <div>Rendering Component John</div>;

class Names extends React.Component {
  state = {
    componentId: ""
  };
  components = () => {
    switch (this.state.componentId) {
      case "donald":
        return <Donald />;
      case "john":
        return <John />;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };
  showComponent = id => {
    this.setState({ componentId: id });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="info">{this.components()}</div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => this.showComponent("donald")}>
            My name Donald
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => this.showComponent("john")}>
            My name John
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Names />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root' />
```